# Is there a way to find out if I am running inside a Flatpak, AppImage or another sandboxed environment in C?

Tags: c, linux, sandbox

I want to rewrite a part of my library to work with Flatpaks and other sandboxed environments which may have limitations on my permissions. Is there a way to determine whether the process is inside such an environment?

Comment: systemd-detect-virt -> https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/detect-virt/detect-virt.c#L164 -> https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/dd003f1621967f114a6a808bb1f729386dc3a154/src/basic/virt.c#L795

Comment: Seems to be specific to `systemd`, I want something working with all init systems (And configurations).

Comment: I would say, check for the permissions you need directly.  That is, instead of knowing that environment X won't let you do thing Y, and trying to detect environment X (which bakes in a "fact" about environment X which might not be universal, and may also be difficult to detect), focus on finding out whether you can do thing Y, if necessary just by trying to do thing Y and noticing that it failed.

Comment: All my library does is create dialogs, and in this case I wanted to open a dialog through a DBus bus instead of using a library for it if I'm running inside a Flatpak. So basically this can't be applied.

Comment: `Seems to be specific to systemd` The source code is in C.... ? Also, the method is the same, irrelevant of the tool.

Comment: True, but it would then be a violation of the LGPL to use it since my library is MIT licensed and I'd have to relicense it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `argv[0]` give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, it seems like there are a few ways to detect a container with only a few lines of code. For Flatpak, the environment variable `container` is set. On AppImage, the `APPIMAGE` env is set. For snaps I couldn't find something appropriate, it looks like there are a few environment variables that are set though: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/environment-variables/7983

Most likely, in code implementation, it would look like this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_container(void) {
    if (getenv("container")) {
        /* flatpak */
        return true;
    } else if (getenv("APPIMAGE")) {
        /* AppImage */
        return true;
    } else if (getenv("SNAP")) {
        /* Snaps */
        return true;
    }
    return false; /* No container detected */
}
```